# set multiple headers with fastify

Tags: node.js, fastify

i wish to set the same header as the following one but with fastify framework

```
// working example with express    
const head = {
          'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
          'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
          'Content-Length': chunksize,
          'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
```

Right now i am doing that (with fastify), but it does not work(or look like)

```
reply
    .header('Content-Type','video/mp4')
    .header('Content-Lenght', chunksize)
    .header('Accept-Range', 'bytes')
    .header('Content-Range', `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`)
    .send(str)
```

I did not find any example of multiple header with fastify.
The header's contents does not matter, i just need to know how to set it up correctly.
Thank you

Comment: Your code is fine, what is not working? did you added a `foo: bar` response header?

Comment: @Manuel, Thank you for you feedback. With the first header (with express, or node-core http-module so) the range works when i display the video in the browser after Streaming it. But when i run the exact same code with fastify, only modifying the header, the range does not work any-more. So i had a doubt about my header... But as you said that is fine, i probably need to look for the issue somewhere else.

Comment: How you are managing the stream to send ranges?

Comment: The issue is from the headers, as you said Manuel the header is fine but the status-code is missing, i added a line `.code(206)` and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple headers at once using the `headers` method:

```js
reply
  .code(206)
  .headers({
    'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': chunksize,
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
  })
  .send(str);
```

Really what you have is also correct, but it sounds like you just needed to add the `.code(206)` to the reply.